# How to get consistent AJAX response in all .NET Frameworks?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-3.5

As of ASP.NET 3.5, all AJAX responses from ASP.NET Web Services are enclosed inside a `d` object.

> This is the case with all ASMX services JSON serialized through the
>   ASP.NET AJAX Extensions in ASP.NET 3.5. Even if you’re only returning
>   a scalar return value, such as a string, int, or boolean, the result
>   will always be enclosed within the “d”.

[*http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/*](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/)

Therefore with pre-3.5 applications you'd do the following:

```
success(data)
{
   var value = data;
}
```

With 3.5+ you must do:

```
success(data)
{
   var value = data.d;
}
```

I've got an application which is ran on post-3.5 and pre-3.5.

How can I keep my code consistent for these applications?

Also this would be useful so that I don't have to change the code in the pre-3.5 applications when they are upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have a little helper function:

```
function GiveMeMyDamnData(data){
   if(data.d)
      return data.d;
   return data;
}
```

then...

```
success(data)
{
   var value = GiveMeMyDamnData(data);
}
```

...just need to make sure you never use a 'd' property in the AJAX response (else that will get confusing!

Comment: +1 I like this, but remembering not to use `d` all the time could be costly. I'd forget my shoes if they weren't sewn into my feet :S

Comment: @Curt: If you need to explicitly avoid using `d` then you don't deserve to have your code work. `d` is not a suitable name for any property... ever ;)

Comment: @Curt I'm more concerned about why your shoes are sewn into your feet.